# Eigenvalues of $AB+BA$ and $AB-BA$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

When can one have the eigenvalues of $AB+BA$ or $AB-BA$ in the range $[0,1]$? Are there any constraints on the matrices $A$ and $B$ such that the above statement holds? I am particularly interested in the case when $dim. A = dim. B = 2$.

Comment: Besides, before considering the $n \times n$ general case, have you an idea  for the case $n=2$ ; have you made attempts using random matrices with Python ?

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question. I am interested in the case of square matrices of dimension 2. I have no experience with Python, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

*Answer for the second case.*

A [classical result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)) says that for any two square matrices $A$ and $B$:

$$trace(AB)=trace(BA)$$

By linearity of trace operator, we deduce that $trace(AB-BA)=0.$

Besides, the trace of a matrix is also the sum of its eigenvalues.

Therefore $\lambda_2=-\lambda_1.$

As a consequence, the only case where both eigenvalues are in $[0,1]$ is when $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=0$ which means that $AB-BA$ is necessarily the zero matrix.